# How can I fix a parameter forward dependency in SSRS when dependent parameter is the parameter itself?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have what seems to be  a common problem, but it doesn’t  fit with any of the proposed solutions I’ve found. I’m using SQL Server 2012.

The error is:

> “An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of
>   the repot ‘/Employees by Job Function' is invalid. The report
>   parameter ‘JobFunction’ has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that
>   depends on the report parameter ‘JobFunction.’ Forward dependencies
>   are not valid”

I have two parameters in the following order:
@UserName
@JobFunction
The @UserName pulls the User!UserID global.
The @JobFunction is tied to the following dataset (JobFunctions) for both Available Values and Defaul  Values. It does not allow nulls or multiple values:

```
--DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(25) = 'abs34949'
DECLARE @SystemAdmin INT
SELECT @SystemAdmin = 
 (SELECT TOP (1) e.EmployeeId
FROM ref.Employee AS e
LEFT JOIN sec.Employee_JobFunction AS ejf ON e.EmployeeId = ejf.EmployeeId
WHERE e.StaffId = @UserName
AND (ejf.JobFunctionId = 2 --System Administration
OR e.EmployeeTypeId = 83) --CTSU
AND e.EmployeeStatusId = 1 --Active
AND e.StaffId IS NOT NULL
)
IF @SystemAdmin IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SELECT jf.JobFunctionId
, jf.JobFunctionName
FROM sec.JobFunction AS jf
ORDER BY jf.JobFunctionName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT 0 AS JobFunctionId
, 'You are not authorized to run this report' AS JobFunctionName
END
```

The Dataset for the Report itself  is a stored procedure using the following code:

```
--DECLARE @JobFunction INT = 155 --Property Admin 
SELECT l.LocationName
, e.DisplayName
FROM sec.JobFunction AS jf
INNER JOIN sec.Employee_JobFunction AS ejf ON jf.JobFunctionId = ejf.JobFunctionId
INNER JOIN ref.Employee AS e ON ejf.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN ref.Location AS l ON e.DefaultLocationId = l.LocationId
WHERE jf.JobFunctionId = @JobFunction
ORDER BY l.LocationName, e.DisplayName
```

I’m just not seeing where the JobFunction parameter is misplaced, or what else could be causing this error message.

Comment: Are you using first dataset for the default values for the second dataset?

Comment: Have you tried changing the @JobFunction parameter to run the query in "default values" property "get values from a query"?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is as you don't seem to be using the JobFucntion parameter in your JobFunction dataset. What I did notice is that you said "It does not allow nulls or multiple values" but your job functions dataset can return multiple values. First thing I would do is remove the default values and see if you still get the error.If not then decide if you need multiple job functions in your report and change the dataset or parameter properties accordingly.